# include_path error when trying to access app in localhost

Tags: php, facebook, apache

I realize that a question thread already exists, but it has been closed since and the OP hadn't responded to the answer. The question thread can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547333/include-path-c-php5-pear

So, my problem is this:

I have my facebook app locally in my htdocs folder (my DocumentRoot) and it requires sdk/src/facebook.php. I receive the following error upon trying to view the page:

```
Warning: require_once(sdk/src/facebook.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Apache\Apache2\htdocs\www\immense-headland-4743\index.php on line 14

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'sdk/src/facebook.php' (include_path='d:\php\pear') in D:\Apache\Apache2\htdocs\www\immense-headland-4743\index.php on line 14
```

I have tried variations of the backslash and forward slash in my php.ini file; I have tried set_initial_path() and init_set() in my main index.php - but nothing works. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to see the problem here because I was blindly following an existing code and did not look into it carefully. The solution was to look at the php.ini file and see where the include_path variable was pointing - it was pointing to my php installation folder while the php I required was in my apache folder. So I pointed the variable to that folder and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy:Cups in [Trouble with local host PHP require_once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172982/trouble-with-local-host-php-require-once)

As he said : If you put your include/ folder into this folder;

/Users/jfloyd/IOD/includes/

Then alter this line in your PHP ini from:

```
include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php'
```

TO

```
include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php:/Users/jfloyd/IOD/'
```

Then save the file and restart your server, then the include files should be found.

This ini directive can be set in any number of places, in each file, in each folder using .htaccess or in httpd.conf or in the ini file, as I just described.