# How to access config.php file from multi level subdirectories?

Tags: php, subdirectory

I'm having dubts on my website's structure. I've a config, lib and public folders in the root. config contains the config.php and other similiar, lib contains all php/html content (header, each page content, footer etc), while public folder contains all the subfolders for each page with the index.php inside. I did this for the url... Anyway, each of these index.php set their page name in a variable and call the config.php file and a module.php for the whole content. 
My problem is that since I have multi level subdirectory (news/sport/football) each index.php have different config path to call. The "deepest" files have many "../" before config/config.php.

Here's the index.php inside public/news/:

```
<?php  
require '../../config/config.php';


$MainPage = 'news';
$CurPage = 'news';


include_once(LIB_PATH. 'modules.php');  
?>
```

So, is there any way to get the absolute root dir so that the path is the same in all files?
Also, is this structure correct?

Comment: Where is LIB_PATH defined, and what server are you using?

Comment: LIB_PATH is defined in config.php as well as other global defines. I work on it with EasyPhp on my pc and is temporarily in Altervista's servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call config.php from anywhere using an absolute path.

```
include "/config/config.php";
```

You cannot do this because PHP's ini_path does not include your directory.

Try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172982/trouble-with-local-host-php-require-once/16173105#16173105) about where/how to add a directory to your php.ini path.

Answer (score -1):

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/config.php';
```

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT gives me a weird root. Is that because I'm using an alias with EasyPhp? Also on the server gives me weird path...